# Android ProgressBar color not displaying correctly on tablet

Tags: android, xml, progress-bar

I am trying to make an app in Android Studio. In the app I have a progress bar. On the phone the color is displayed correctly like this: 
https://ibb.co/ChK208w (Sorry, SO didn't allow me to post images)

And on the tablet it is displayed like this:
https://ibb.co/rpMKL0h

Here is my progress bar code for color:

```
 <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"

       ............

        android:progressBackgroundTint="#FAFAFA"
        android:progressTint="#D8EDD5" />
```

Any ideas what could cause the tablet version of the app to display the progress bar like that?

Comment: `android:indeterminateTint="#FAFAFA"`

Answer (score 0):

Use the prefix `app:` while using tint attributes like

```
app:progressBackgroundTint="#FAFAFA"
app:progressTint="#D8EDD5"
```